# Flash Filling in Excel when a Filter is applied

Tags: excel

I need to flash fill a column with 1,039 rows ( 001, 002, 003 etc etc) of 2428 rows. Because of the filtering enabled, I can’t flash fill. Normally I would turn off filtering whilst I flash filled but I get too many extra rows.

I have tried using 2 formulas; Rows (rows()) and Subtotal (SUBTOTAL(3,$A$3:A3)) but I can only use it if the values are the same but not flash filling.

Could someone help out with this issue.

Appreciate all the help I can get.

Thank you in advance!